# How to create settings per organisation

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to create a script that stores settings in a separate database via JDBC. However, I want a couple of unique features that I'm not sure that GAS can supply:

1. I want to have settings that are applied at an organisation level (so if the current user is logged in to a Google account that is tied to an organisation/business, I can use settings stored for that organisation
2. I want administrator users of that organisation/business to be able to change settings that all users can then use.

If a user isn't associated with an organisation/business, then it would use user-specific settings, and I can already deal with that, I assume, by using the `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()` method?

Comment: since you already know how the user email, you know their domain. you mean you want to also cover the case a gsuite client might have multiple domains under the same  customerId?

Comment: Yeah, or they might have external people collaborating on a document, so the email is `consultant@example.com`, but the Google Apps domain is `@company.com`.